# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove') or (reading 'add')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know it's a newbie problem, but... I have a set of lists I want to display

```
<div class="podcasts-list-1 podcasts-list-visible"> </div>
<div class="podcasts-list-2"> </div>
<div class="podcasts-list-3"> </div>
```

based on the value of a page that is being clicked.

```
<ul> <li class="podcasts-page-item" value="1" onclick="selectPodcastsList()">
                1
      </li>

      <li class="podcasts-page-item" value="2" onclick="selectPodcastsList()">
                2
      </li>

      <li class="podcasts-page-item" value="3" onclick="selectPodcastsList()">
                3
      </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code in JS:

```
const podcastsListOne = document.getElementsByClassName("podcasts-list-1")
const podcastsListTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("podcasts-list-2")
const podcastsListThree = document.getElementsByClassName("podcasts-list-3")

function selectPodcastsList () {
    currentValue = event.target.value;
    if (currentValue === 1) {
        console.log(currentValue)
        podcastsListOne.classList.add("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListTwo.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListThree.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
    } else if (currentValue === 2) {
        console.log(currentValue)
        podcastsListOne.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListTwo.classList.add("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListThree.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
    } else if (currentValue === 3) {
        console.log(currentValue)
        podcastsListOne.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListTwo.classList.remove("podcasts-list-visible")
        podcastsListThree.classList.add("podcasts-list-visible")
    }
}
```

However, every time I click on

item, I see an error which says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')". Why is that so? What would be the correct code in order to avoid that and achieve my goal?

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements. You have to iterate through the list and work with each element individually.

Comment: @Pointy oh my god yes, I changed it to `querySelector()` and now it is working as intended! Thank you so much!